# 403 error when displaying user avatar from Firestore Google Sign-in

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuetify.js, google-signin

In my Vue app I am using Firestore Authentication with Google Sign-in enabled. Once the user signs in, I receive some basic information including the `photoURL`. However, when I try to render it in a component, I am getting a 403 error.

Vuetify component:

```html
<v-img :src="user.photoURL" /> <!-- https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/xxxxxxxxxxxxx -->
```

Error:

```
GET https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/xxxxxxxxxxxxx 403
```

I tried applying the solution of adding the [`referrerpolicy="no-referrer"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) attribute to the component, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to do something specific with the Firebase API?

Answer (score 8):

I think you have a little mistake in your solution.
For noreferrer policy you must to try:

```
   rel="noreferrer"
```

Or:

```
   referrerpolicy="origin"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this attr `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"` helped me

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a little mistake in your solution. For optional chaining you must try:

```
src="user?.photoURL"
```

or

```
src={user?.photoURL}
```